# cannot create the private integration for API gateeway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb, aws-api-gateway

I created the service, deployment and ingress files and deployed my service in EKS cluster in AWS. The service runs fine i.e. I can see 200 for my endpoint. Now I wanted to put an API-gateway in front.

I tried to create an API gateway with a proxy resource from [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html]. When I was trying to test my API/URL endpoint, I got 500 saying `Invalid Endpoint address` and then I found that I have to setup the private integration [https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-invalid-endpoint-address/]

1. I created the NLB. I do not have listener rules right now.[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/network-load-balancer-getting-started.html]
2. I created the VPCLink with the NLB arn[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vpc-links.html]
3. Then, finally I am following the steps illustrated here [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-private-integration.html]. When I am trying to `test` the api-proxy, I am getting `Execution failed due to configuration error: There was an internal error while executing your request`

Comment: I would sugest to simply qestion, and just focus on one issue only.

Comment: @Marcin: Can I get some help on how to find the actual reason for `Execution failed due to configuration error: There was an internal error while executing your request`

Comment: @Marcin When I am trying to `test` the API endpoint, I cannot even see it hitting in my kibana logs. While, if I copy the url `https://www.example.com/v1/ping` I see that in kibana.